# Add a right click menu in an text% context in Racket (popup-menu%)

Tags: user-interface, mouseevent, racket

In [`editor<%>`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/editor___.html?q=editor%3C%25%3E) classes in Racket, I can overwrite [`on-default-event`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/editor___.html?q=editor%3C%25%3E#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._editor~3c~25~3e%29._on-default-event%29%29), to determine if the right mouse button was clicked. Now I would like a right click menu to show up with, say, cut/copy/paste options. Is this possible to do with and `editor<%>`? I would rather not add it directly to the `frame%` if that is possible, because I am planning on using the `editor<%>` as a snip.

Answer (score 2):

I have an example in Bracket where right-clicking a math box (a snip in which you can enter mathematical expressions) show a small menu.

https://github.com/soegaard/bracket/blob/master/gui/racket-cas.rkt#L320